# to check if a number have already been used in a array java

Tags: java, arrays

Answering the comments:
Yes, I do know I have not searched for anything. I don't know how, kind of the reason I am here
No, I don't need you to write the code from me, simply show me how it is done so I can learn
I have tried different things, but did not want to mess my code with things that did not work

question: I need to check if the input have been used before, If not I want to add it to the array, if not I want to ask again.

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("What's the length of the array?");
int lengde = keyboard.nextInt();                   
int[] myArray = new int[lengde]; 


for (int i = 0; i < lengde; i++) {
  System.out.println((i+1) + (" give a number"));
  int used = keyboard.nextInt(); 

  //if  used have been added before
   // System.out.println("pick a new number");

  //else // used have not been added before
    myArray[i] = used;

} 
for (int i : myArray)
  System.out.println(i);

keyboard.close();
```

Comment: You are not checking whether the number is already present. You are just adding the number to the array.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Such as searching through the array looking for the number?

Comment: Yes I know I dont check if the number is present, I dont know how to. That was what I came her asking about

Comment: We're not here to write your code for you. You have to at least try! Really think about the problem you are trying to solve and give it a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to check would be as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lengde; ) {
  int readInt = keyboard.nextInt();
  boolean found = false;
  for(int index=0; index < i; index++) {
    intFromArray = myArray[index]; // Get element from array
    if(readInt == intFromArray) {
      found = true; // Number already in array
      break;
    }
  }
  // Number not found in the array. Add it to the array.
  if(!found) {
    myArray[i] = readInt;
    i++;
  } else {
       System.out.println("Found in array. Try again...");
  }

}
```

You might want to allow a certain number of tries only, otherwise it will loop indefinitely.

Comment: there seems to be something wrong, I can still get the output 1,2,1?

Comment: Did you use the exact code or modified anything? I have added retrieval of number from array now. Had missed that.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) instead of a primitive array. It provides the `#contains` method out of the box, and will preserve the original element insertion order.

```
LinkedHashSet<Integer> collection = new LinkedHashSet<>();
for (int i = 0; i < lengde; ) {
  int readInt = keyboard.nextInt();
  boolean added = collection.add(readInt);
  if (!added) {
    System.out.println("Found in array. Try again...");
  }
}
```